# WPF: Binding to a custom structure

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I've created custom structure `Date` which internally uses `DateTime` but it's prevents from storing current day time:

```
  public struct Date
    {
        private readonly DateTime _dateTime;
        public Date(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            _dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _dateTime.ToString();
        }
        public static Date Parse(string input)
        {
            return new Date(DateTime.Parse(input));
        }
        //other class members
    }
```

This solution works fine for me, but I'm stuck when I want to take `Date` from user. When I'm binding this type to DatePicker I can't set or get values in binded property:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"/>
```

Property:

```
public Date Date
 {
     get { return _date; }
     set
     {
         _date = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Date");
     }
 }
```

Is there some smart way to have "bindable custom structure"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won´t work, cause the property [SelectedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of the DatePicker control is of type `Nullable<DateTime>` and the runtime cannot implicitly converter your Date struct to a DateTime struct.

What you can do is to implement an `IValueConverter` to convert a DateTime to your Date struct.

For me i would not use my own struct to represent a Date value. You should change your property to DateTime and use the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of the DateTime if you are only interested in the Date value.

```
public DateTime Date
 {
     get { return _date; }
     set
     {
         _date = value.Date;
         OnPropertyChanged("Date");
     }
 }
```

If you want to keep your Date struct then use a IValueConverter, that you assign to your binding to convert Date to DateTime and vice versa.

```
public class DateToDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
      // convert Date to DateTime
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
      //convert DateTime to Date
    }

  }
```

XAML:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource dateToDateTimeConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Introducing custom `Date` was the solution to problems with time zones, I don't want to come back to DateTime.Date...

Comment: @MiłoszWierzbick Did you have a look at `DateTimeOffset` insted of `DateTime`?